# Having trouble converting sin results between degrees and radians

Tags: calculus

If I open the MS calculator and put it in deg mode at take the sin(2.23) I get .0389. Then if I put the calc into rad mode and take the sin(.039) I get .039. If I then use google to convert .039 to degrees, I get 2.23. What is going on here?

Comment: For small $x$, $\sin x$ is approximately $x$. That is, if you are using radians, which of course you should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, it's basically because of the [small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation). As Angina said, this holds for angles measured in radians.

Take for example (in radians) $\sin(1) \approx 0.84$ (~$16$% difference), but $\sin(0.5) \approx 0.48$ (~$1$% difference).

So what you are doing is taking $\sin(2.23º) = 0.389$, then since $\sin(0.0389) \approx 0.0389$, you get the same number in the calculator. And then this same number you convert to degrees. It's only consistent that you get the same $2.23º$.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like what you're saying is that, despite the input in the calc being in deg, the output is in rad. If I assume that, things seem to line up.

Comment: Not really. I think your misunderstanding comes from the fact that the output of $\sin$ is a real number, not an angle. But this could be confusing at first because of how radians are defined. See first part in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) to understand how they are defined, especially the animation.

Comment: Really? If I take the sin in deg of 50, I get .766. If I convert 50 to radians, I get .873. If I take the sin in radians of .873, I get .766. So it seems like the MS calc is outputting in rad no matter what the input is.

Comment: So you can start with an angle $x$, say it's in degrees. Then compute $y = \sin(x)$. This $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ is a real number. But if you then want to calculate $\sin(y)$, you would have to specify whether you want y radians or y degrees in your calculator.

Comment: Look at it this way: The only thing that's happening is that both operations give the same real number as output. In fact, the conversion from radians to degrees or viceversa that you know of is done that way precisely to maintain this property. Thus $\sin(xº) = \sin(xº \frac{\pi}{180º}$

Answer (score 0):

The biggest error occurs when setting 2.23 deg equal to 0.039 rads. It will be more precise if you use: $ [\operatorname{rad}] = \frac{[\deg]\pi}{180} $

Comment: But 2.23*pi/180 is .039. Or extremely close to in anyway. My issue is that after I take the sin in rad, I need to convert the result to degrees. And the results between the 2 aren't matching up.